# Object visible in render mode, but not when rendering animation (with alpha values)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Hi –– I know this is a frequent question, but when I try to render my animation (cycles render), the viewport, and the files it outputs (I've tried PNGs and movies), are blank (transparent, as I'm using alpha background). I've gone through every tip I can find: the camera icon is enabled, the object is within distance of camera, I have a ton of lights, I restarted my computer, I'm rendering the correct scene and layer, I'm compositing correctly. I've also rendered this correctly in the past, but can't remember how I got it to work. Link to file here: [image]

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Your material "shinyblue.001" is basically just a mirror and your environment (world) is a dark gray hence *this blob of something*. Recommend try Blender 2.8 for better preview and use any environment texture (hdri)... And render to an image sequence in general (also to find the issues of your file) then composite all together.